# How to join different tables in sqlalchemy query having same column names?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, join, sqlalchemy

Description of the tables are:

```
License: id, customer_id, product_id, expires_at
Customer: id, name
Product: id, name
```

I am querying like this:

```
result = session.\
            query(License.id, License.customer_id, License.product_id, License.status, License.expires_at,\
                  Customer.name,\
                  Product.name).\
            # some filtering on those columns (JOIN conditions)
            all()
```

I want the joined table to contain:

```
License.id, Customer.name, Product.name
```

Now the `result` I am getting is a list of `KeyedTuples`. How can I access the required columns from those? e.g. `result[0].name` gives only `Customer.name`, then how to get `Product.name` as well?

Comment: I would expect you to get "sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Ambiguous column name 'name' in result set column descriptions". At least that is what I get when I try to access columns with the same name via sqlalchemy RowProxy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `label` method:

```
Customer.name.label("Customer_name"),\
Product.name.label("Product_name").\
```

Comment: as I can see Sqlalchemy automatically apply label in query, is there any way to get that labeled column name in result set with manually applying label

Comment: @Sudhakar I don't understand, do you mean **without** manually applying label?

Comment: If you have duplicate column names you have to change one of them manually so you can access both.

Comment: @Barmer yes I want the labeled column, which is applied by Sqlalchemy while querying on db.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. I've never used sqlalchemy myself, I just found the above in the documentation. If you're having a problem with your code, post a question with the details.

Comment: @Barmer, thanks for your response. I am really sorry for the confusion. I will post a question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213809/discussion-between-sudhakar-and-barmar).

Comment: This forces you to declare the fields in the select statement. If you were using a SELECT * then this implies that now you need to add all the individual fields to the query, which is far from ideal. It would be much better to have a way to access them via RowProxy using table prefixes.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62723692/6243352) is a bit clearer of how to use this code in the context of a query.