# Pandas and SQLAlchemy: renaming columns during join

Tags: pandas, select, sqlalchemy, duplicates, rename

I have *table A* and *table B*. Both have a column *id* and a column *name*.
When I use *pd.read_sql()* to convert the result of a SQLAlchemy query to a pandas DataFrame, the resulting DataFrame has two columns named *id* and two columns named *name*.

The join is executed on the *id* column, therefore, even if there are two *id* columns, there won't be any ambiguity since both columns contain the same values. I can simply drop one of the column.

The two columns named *name* represent an issue because they are not identical: column *name* of *table A* represents name of an *entity A*, while column *name* of *table B* represents name of an *entity B*. At this point I won't know for sure which of the two columns of the DataFrame comes from *table A* and which from *table B*. Is there any way to solve this by, for instance, adding a prefix to the column names? More in general, is there any way to exploit the practical *pd.from_sql()* in this situation?

```
my_dataframe = pd.read_sql(
            session.query(TableA, TableB)
                .join(TableB)
                .statement,
            session.bind)
```

Note: in this question I am trying to simplify the structure of a more complex preexisting Postgres database. Therefore, it won't be possible to alter the structure of the database.

Comment: Should be pretty simple to set up a sqlite database with the features you describe. Any chance we could get an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually really simple, but you have to rename each single field:

```
my_dataframe = pd.read_sql(
            session.query(TableA.field1.label('my_new_name1'),
                          TableA.field2.label('my_new_name2'),
                          TableB.field1.label('my_other_name2'))
                .join(TableB)
                .statement,
            session.bind)
```